# How to detect if COM Class method has failed in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dll, error-handling, com

So I have this code in VBA that uses a third party COM class to add a record to a database

```
Function AddPatientToDolphin(ID As String, LastName As String, FirstName As String)
On Error GoTo CatchError
Dim Plst As DOLDBSVRLib.DolphinPatients
Dim Patient As DOLDBSVRLib.DolphinPatient
Set Plst = New DOLDBSVRLib.DolphinPatients
Set Patient = New DOLDBSVRLib.DolphinPatient
Patient.patientID = ID
Patient.LastName = LastName
Patient.FirstName = FirstName
Plst.AddPatient Patient
Set Plst = Nothing
Set Patient = Nothing
NormalExit:
   Exit Function
CatchError:
   MsgBox (Err.Description )
   GoTo NormalExit
End Function
```

The code is fine and it works correctly, except when the ID is already present in the database, then the record will not be added but no error is raised!

in the documentation of the 3rd party dll, there is this instruction regarding this method

HRESULT AddPatient(LPDISPATCH newPatient)
Add a patient represented by the patient object submitted.

After some research, I learned that every method in a COM class returns a value called Hresult. This is supposed to be 0 when everything runs correctly, and not 0 otherwise. My question is how could I pick up and test this value in VBA??

Comment: Trap for the return code - `ReturnCode = Plst.AddPatient(Patient)`

Answer (score 2):

```
HRESULT AddPatient(LPDISPATCH newPatient)
```

This function is declared that so that it has no returncode in VBA. If the returncode is a HRESULT error code, VBA translates this into an exception and sets the code into the Err object.

If the function reacts normal and returns and doesn't show any fault, than the only way is to check if the ID exists. But this is a race condition. Another user may execute the same code.

There is no real answer for this kind of interface if it behaves in this way.

Or contact the guy who is responsable for this COM interface.

Comment: I think you are right, in fact after further research I found that the DolphinPatients object has a prperty called status                                                                         
long Status This contains execution status of the last operation. If zero (0), then no error was detected.

Comment: I can use that property to test whether a patient was successfully added. but can you please tell me is this a limitation in VBA or if it is not possible even with other languages, also why can't i use the method with parenthesis  Plst.AddPatient(Patient) , this seems strange to me, Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No. This is no limitation of COM or VBA. It is possible to construct interfaces that also return the result of the Add function. From my point of few it is an error in the design of the interface. So my advice is to contact the programmer. In such a case when a function fails to 'Add" I will always return a HRESULT error. Or my Add function would return an additional return value about the outcome of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to inspect the return value of the external function. To catch it in a variable:

```
Dim RetVal As Long
RetVal = Plst.AddPatient(Patient)
```

Then, compare to `0` and eventually display an error message:

```
If RetVal <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End If
```

**Added:**

Ok, the call as a function is not allowed in this case, so try this:

```
Plst.AddPatient Patient

If Err.LastDLLError <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End If
```

Comment: This did not work. When I use the method with parenthesis Plst.AddPatient(Patient) I got an error when I run the function "run time error 438 , object does not support this property or method" when I use the method without a parenthesis Plst.AddPatient Patient it works but then VBA editor will not allow me to assign it to a variable and throws a compilwe error syntax error!

Comment: what about checking Plst.Hresult?  (check the value after you add).